# Подключение радио плеера

Tags: html

Всем привет! Можно ли модернизировать этот код под html5 и сделать его более рабочим, а то он очень часто отключается и чтоб радио было слышно приходиться перезагружать страницу.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="SmartPlayer" data="http://host.fm/flash/ExternalPlayer.swf?radio=17817" width="257" height="32">
    <param name="movie" value="http://host.fm/flash/ExternalPlayer.swf?radio=17817">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведенный здесь "код" ни при чем.
Улучшаете ExternalPlayer.swf , если это не Ваша разработка, то поищите не глючный радиоплеер.